# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table does not exist after migrating to Postgres from SQLite

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

After changing my settings and migrating to Postgres I am getting this error while performing
migrations, I previously deleted all my migration folders because I had a similar issue with *database inconsistency*, now I don't have any migrations in my app-level directories, I do have *DB* backup but, how do I get past this, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

**Db Settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 230, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 118, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "customers_user" does not exist
```

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your migrations folders, create new migrations folder and put empty __init__.py into it, then run makemigrations and migrate, note two _ before and after init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As V.D said I had by mistake deleted all migration folders in-app, I had to recreate those folders with **init**.py and then run migrations, issue resolved now